# How do I use modes to change the operation of the template in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xslt

I have the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template name="populateHostSim">
    <xsl:param name="action" />
    <xsl:param name="currentHost" />
    <xsl:param name="currentResult" />

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]">
            <xsl:if test="$action='header'">
                <th>
                    <b>Host / SIM</b>
                </th>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$currentHost">
                <td>
                    <xsl:call-template name="populateSimId">
                        <xsl:with-param name="currentSimResult" select="$currentResult" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="currentSimHost" select="$currentHost" />
                    </xsl:call-template>

                    <b>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$currentHost" />
                    </b>
                </td>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I would like to change it so that if it's called from one template it puts in the html tags:

```
           <th>
                <b>Host / SIM</b>
            </th>
```

but if it's called from another it puts in markup:

```
          ||Host /SIM||
```

I have looked at modes http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works, but I can't figure out how to use them in this context.

Comment: "*I have the following XSLT*" You are only showing one named template, not a complete XSLT. If you want this template to behave differently under different circumstances, use a *parameter*, not *mode*.

Comment: yes, you are correct.